# how to get only value json file text website by python

Tags: python-3.x

My file json :

```
{"Id":94477,"StrId":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u002794477\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003e94477\u003c/a\u003e","Quan":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u0027Bình Tân\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003eBình Tân\u003c/a\u003e","Duong":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u0027Liên Khu 2-10\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003eLiên Khu 2-10\u003c/a\u003e","Gia":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 cred\u0027 title=\u00272.8 Tỷ\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003e2.8 Tỷ\u003c/a\u003e","DienTich2":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u00274x12\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003e4x12\u003c/a\u003e","LoGioi2":"","Huong":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u0027Đông\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003eĐông\u003c/a\u003e","Url":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u0027Chi tiết\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=oa.2342022366052447&type=3\u0027\u003eChi tiết\u003c/a\u003e","ChuNha":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u0027Chị Tuyết\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003eChị Tuyết\u003c/a\u003e","SoNha":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u0027đã bán.17/19 (Hình+Sổ A.Hùng)\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003eđã bán.17/19 (Hình+S\u003c/a\u003e","ViTri":null,"HienTrang":"","Email":"","LuotXem":6,"DienThoai":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u00270934942927\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003e0934942927\u003c/a\u003e","Phuong":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u0027Bình Hưng Hoà A\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003eBình Hưng Hoà A\u003c/a\u003e","NgayTao":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u002706/09/2019\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003e06/09/2019\u003c/a\u003e","IsHot":true,"HienTrang2":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u00271 Tấm\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003e1 Tấm\u003c/a\u003e","LoGioi":"\u003ca class=\u0027title-8 \u0027 title=\u00276M\u0027 target=\u0027_blank\u0027 href=\u0027/Detail.aspx?Index=94477\u0027\u003e6M\u003c/a\u003e","CurrentMember":{"Id":10229,"Role":"Member","Username":"quang032018","Ten":"Quang Btra"},"OwnerId":10154,"ChoiceItemIds":[75877,60468,84656,83414,84419,83007,60545,83357,84699,83012,79450,60644,92436,92437],"Map":null,"Cancel":"","Choose":"\u003ca href=\u0027javascript:void(0);\u0027 class=\u0027pointer inblock w4\u0027 ref=\u002794477\u0027 onclick=chooseItem(this);return false;\u0027\u003eChọn\u003c/a\u003e","Sua":"","Xoa":"","Up":"","CanEdit":false,"IsChose":false}
```

My code :

```
import json

data = json.load(open("tem.txt", encoding='utf-8-sig'))

for x in data:
    print("%s: %s" % (x, data[x]))
```

How to get only value , dont have

Comment: what is your expected result? what means that "dont have"?

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the json text first, and

```
import json

data = json.load(open("test.txt", encoding='utf-8-sig'))

for k, v in data.items():
    if v is None:
        print(k, v)
    elif v == '':
        print(k, v)
```

gives the results

```
LoGioi2 
ViTri None
HienTrang 
Email 
Map None
Cancel 
Sua 
Xoa 
Up
```